# Shopify external database connection

Tags: database, shopify, connector

I'm looking for the best solution to retrieve and post data from an external database. What type and where the database is stored is still up for discussion. Whatever is the fastest and easiest to implement with shopify will be chosen. Ideally it would be a javascript implemention. The data that has to be passed would be a string and non float values.

Comment: This is a bit generic. The answerer is correct though, if you just need a simple remote storage, serverless (lambda, cloud functions) + simple NoSQL db (dynamoDB, firestore, mongoDB atlas) is fine. If it's something that can be stored using Shopify features, just use that.

Some follow ups you might need to answer to get deeper help:
- what data are you storing, and where is it sourced from exactly? I know you said "string and nonfloat values" but what is this, and where does it come from?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit too broad, I'll just try give you some advice, based on my experience.

I can think of two different approaches, depending on differenct factors (how many entries you need, how they are structured, etc).

1. Serverless

You won't need a Shopify app for this. Just create and endpoint (lambda+API Gateway with DynamoDB) like `GET yourapidomain.com/mydata?myParam=2` and `POST yourapidomain.com/mydata` be careful with CORS, and you're done. This approach is quite generic, it can work in any situation.

2. Using metafields

If you don't have too many entries, and the structure is quite simple, you can use the metafields on Shopify as database.

If, for example, your data is for each product you can save it in the metafields of the product (or of the customer, etc).
You will still need an endpoint to post the data from your page but you will be able to retrieve the data from the liquid file (server side).

Without knowing your particular use case is difficult to go more into details.

Comment: Thank you, yes it was meant to be generic as I'm still figuring out the needs. I do know there will be a lot of entries and metafields won't work